# Both relationships could use MatchId as foreign key

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-5.0

I have a problem with EF Core code first class object mapping. I have a class **Match** where I have properties for Team A and Team B.

```
public class Match: MyEntity
    {
        public virtual Team TeamA { get; private set; }

        public virtual Team TeamB { get; private set; }

        public GameType GameType { get; private set; }

        public MatchStatus Status { get; private set; }

        public Match()
        {
 
        }
```

Here my Team entity, where I have reference on **MatchId**.

```
    public class Team: MyEntity
    {
        public virtual int MatchId { get; private set; }

        private Team()
        { }
        ...
    }
```

So I need MatchId be the same for TeamA and TeamB in case they are in the same match.
When I am trying to create migration, I have an error:

**Both relationships between 'Team' and 'Match.TeamA' and between 'Team' and 'Match.TeamB' could use {'MatchId'} as the foreign key. To resolve this, configure the foreign key properties explicitly in 'OnModelCreating' on at least one of the relationships.**

---

```
 builder.Entity<Team>()
.HasOne<Match>()
.WithOne(x => x.TeamA)
.HasForeignKey<Team>(x => x.MatchId);
  
builder.Entity<Team>()
.HasOne<Match>()
.WithOne(x => x.TeamB)
.HasForeignKey<Team>(x => x.MatchId);
```

When I am using this configuration it works, but it is  deleting in migration **`TeamAId`** and **`TeamBId`** columns from **`Matches`** table and creates two columns in **`Team`** table: **`MatchId`** and **`MatchId1`**.

```
      migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "TeamAId",
                table: "Matches");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "TeamBId",
                table: "Matches");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "MatchId",
                table: "Teams",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "MatchId1",
                table: "Teams",
                type: "int",
                nullable: true);
```

Maybe am I missing something?

How should I fix this ?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it with not relying on default EF Core configurations, but on mine in `OnModelCreating`. Hope I did it in right way, someone can tell if see something wrong.

```
 builder.Entity<Team>(b =>
            {
                b.HasOne<Match>()
                    .WithOne(x => x.TeamA)
                    .HasForeignKey<Team>(x => x.MatchId);

                b.HasOne<Match>()
                    .WithOne(x => x.TeamB)
                    .HasForeignKey<Team>(x => x.MatchId);
            });

   builder.Entity<Match>(b =>
            {
                   b.HasOne<Team>("TeamA")
                  .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("TeamAId");

                b.HasOne<Team>("TeamB")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("TeamBId");

                b.Navigation("TeamA");

                b.Navigation("TeamB");
            });
```